# How to split an array in to specific values

Tags: php

I would like to split my array into different tasks;

for example:

```
 $employee = [
   "1010" => "110",
   "1011" => "110",
   "1015" => "110",
   "1017" => "120",
   "1018" => "120",
   "1020" => "150",
   "1050" => "150",
   "1052" => "150",
   "1055" => "150" 
];
```

The `key` is the `employee_id` and the `value` is a `task`.
Now i would like to iterate over this array and get seperatly shown the tasks like so:

```
**TASK 110**
  1010 110
  1011 110
  1015 110
**TASK 120**
  1017 120
  1018 120
**TASK 150**
  1020 150
  1050 150
  1052 150
  1055 150
```

What is the best way to achieve this:

```
foreach($employee as $empl => $task)
 {
    echo $empl . " " . $task . "<br>";

 }
```

This show me all employee_id and tasks.
I have tried to use the function `array_chunk` but didn't work because this splits only to a static size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if array is not ordered before, use one more loop

```
foreach($employee as $empl => $task) {
  $temp[$task][] = $empl;
}

foreach($temp as $task=> $list ) {
      echo "**TASK $task**<br>";
      foreach($list as $empl) {
        echo $empl . " " . $task . "<br>";
      }
 }
```

[demo](https://eval.in/896138)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a record for the header, then compare it on every row and echo the header if changed

```
$record = '';
foreach($employee as $empl => $task)
 {
    if ($taks !== $record) {
        echo "**TASK " . $task . "**<br>";
        $record = $taks;
    }
    echo $empl . " " . $task . "<br>";

 }
```